# How to generate code for Simulink model which contains an export-function submodel?

Tags: code-generation, simulink

I'm using matlab 2019b to build this Simulink model: A function call generator calls an export-fuction submodel. [image: TopModel]
An export-function model is a model with function call inputs.
[image: SubModel]

I can generate code for the submodel using embedded coder, as well as run simulation of the top model. But generating code for the top model gives this error message:

> Model 'main' contains a reference model 'main/Model' that is set up as a multi-instance export-function, but model 'main' does not follow export-function rules.
> where 'main' is the top model name.

The export-function model document *https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/export-function-models.html* writes:

> For function-call Model blocks, Periodic sample time constraint for the referenced model set to Ensure sample time independent

Following this rule throws another errors. If the top model's periodic sample time constraint is changed, the error is:

> This model will not inherit a sample time because the block 'main/Model' disallows it from doing so.  If this model does not need to inherit a sample time, change the "Periodic sample time constraint" to something other than "Ensure sample time independent" on the Solver tab of the Configuration Parameters dialog.

And if the submodel's periodic sample time constraint is changed, the error is:

> The current diagnostic settings for model 'instance' are not valid because the model contains root-level Inport block 'instance/f' that outputs a function-call signal. See errors reported below for details.
> Caused by:
> In the export-function model 'instance', the parameter 'Periodic sample time constraint' in 'Configuration Parameters' > 'Solver' > 'Tasking and sample time options' must be set to 'Unconstrained'.
> Suggested Actions
> Set the 'Periodic sample time constraint' to 'Unconstrained' in 'instance'.

How can I generate code for the top model?

Comment: What have you set the step time to? Are you using a discrete time solver?